# How one can know the gauge field emerging from the local gauge invariance is actually the EM field?

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, field-theory, gauge-invariance

How one can know the gauge field emerging from the local gauge invariance is actually the EM field?

I understood in a simple scalar field whose Lagrangian is given by

$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \phi)^{*}(\partial^\mu \phi) - \frac{1}{2} |\phi|^2 $

needs a vector gauge field in order to satisfy the local gauge invariance, which is simply

the electromagnetic field $A_\mu$.

What I'm trying to understand is that how one can prove that gauge field

is exactly an EM field that satisfy the Maxwell's eqn:
$\partial_\mu \partial^{[\space\mu} A^{\nu \space]} = J^\nu$.

For making the Lagrangian be locally gauge invariant, the field $A_\mu$, whatever it is,

I showed it should have a gauge transformation relation

$A_\mu \rightarrow A_\mu ' = A_\mu - \partial_\mu \chi $ as $\phi 
\rightarrow \phi' = e^{-i\chi}\phi$

I think however, it doesn't guarantee that $A_\mu$ should be the EM field

that satisfies above Maxwell's eqn.

Please let me understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

OP asks (v1):

> *How one can know the gauge field emerging from the local gauge invariance is actually the EM field?*

Assuming that OP is pondering about gauging theoretical models (rather than concerned with our actual world and phenomenological inputs) then the answer is: *One cannot know.* For starters, the gauge group $G$ could be different than $U(1)$. And even if the gauge group is $G=U(1)$, then it could be another $U(1)$ than $U(1)_{EM}$.

Comment: OP seems focused on the "EM field" fulfilling Maxwell's equations. Any $\mathrm{U}(1)$ field will fulfill Maxwell's equations, just perhaps for a current other than the electromagnetic one.

Comment: Yeah, since OP talked about gauging a (matter) theory, I was mainly concerned with the eom for the matter rather than the eom for the gauge field. For all we know the gauge field action could be, say,  the Born-Infeld action rather than the Maxwell action.